# Induced e.m.f and induced current in a Electro Magnet during Electro Magnetic Induction

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electric-current, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

I just read about Electro-Magnetic Induction and few questions came into my mind, which I can not solve by myself.

**1.** When a coil(Let's say it's a 5 turn coil) connected in a circuit in series, when we switch on the circuit, a current will pass through the whole coil

My question is, when the current will pass through the 1st turn , the induced current will be developed in the 1st wound,and it will reduce the actual current heavily, so when the current will reach the 2nd wound, the current will be much smaller than the 1st wound and it can be 0 at the last wound(i.e - 5th wound)..so there will be no magnetic flux at all.

```
But I have never seen such thing in any where, 
Am I thinking it in a wrong way?
Will the induced current will be generated after the current passes through all wounds (i.e - 5 here)?or it will start generating after the current just passes a single wound??
```

**2**. What will be the North pole and the South pole of the electro magnet??.
The induced current and the actual current will have different directions, so which direction will be used when I am trying to figure out the pole directions??

(I AM CONSIDERING A DC VOLTAGE SOURCE FOR THE BOTH QUESTIONS)

Comment: By wound, do you mean coil?

Comment: The turns of the coil indeed 

Answer (score 2):

**1** *My question is,  . . . . . . , the induced current will be developed in the 1st wound,and it will reduce the actual current heavily, so when the current will reach the 2nd wound,  . . . . . . so there will be no magnetic flux at all.*

Not so.  The change affects **all** the circuit "instantaneously".

**2**  *What will be the North pole and the South pole of the electro magnet??*

When the current is unceasing in the circuit the current driven by the battery will always "win" and so the polarity is determined by the direction of the current due to the battery.